# dpkg-buildpackage: error: failed to sign .dsc file

Tags: gnupg, debian-packaging

I have scripts that build large numbers of debian packages. When I try to set the changelog from UNRELEASED to a specific release so that I can sign the results, I get this error on
every second dpkg-buildpackage:

gpg: signing failed: Broken pipe
gpg: dpkg-sign.fwxloLTb/libshipscomms_4.00-1.dsc: clear-sign failed: Broken pipe

dpkg-buildpackage: error: failed to sign .dsc file

Building the same package a second time immediately after this works fine.

Comment: Clarification: the builds are done inside a makefile not directly on the command line.

Comment: More Clarification: The above happens on three different computers (two architectures) all of which are on Buster 10.10. Another machine whose debian_version file says "buster/sid" works properly. It asks for the key password once and then signs all of the packages as they are built. This sort of makes me think there might be some sort of timeout in gpg.